# unable to write into observable ? using write inside computed

Tags: knockout.js

I am having a function , inside to it i am doing some calculation and i want to write the calculated result to observable .

**View Model:**

```
    function data()
    {
    var innerself=this;
    innerself.Amount=ko.observable("");
    innerself.Volume = ko.observable("");
    innerself.Rate=ko.observable("");

    innerself.AutoCalculate = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    var qty = innerself.Volume();
                    var val = qty * innerself.Rate();
              //  innerself.Amount(val.toFixed(2)); its wrong to use like this i feel
                    return val;
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    innerself.Amount(value); // kept break point but its not getting hit at all but read function excecutes 
                }
            },innerself);
    }
```

**View :**

```
//running loop on top via foreach:observablearray
<input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Volume " />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Rate"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Amount"/>
```

I am using embedding everything in function so later i create a object to it and push the object to observablearray and so on and i will loop through that observablearray in view .

Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: What's the question?  Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: no error mate everything is fine but amount is remians blank becoz write not even firing i believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recalculate Amount automatically

```
function data() {
    var innerself = this;
    innerself.Amount = ko.observable(0);
    innerself.Volume = ko.observable(0);
    innerself.Rate = ko.observable(0);

    ko.computed(function() {
        innerself.Amount(innerself.Volume() * innerself.Rate());
    }, innerself);
}
```

or use Amount as computed

```
function data() {
    var innerself = this;
    innerself.Volume = ko.observable(0);
    innerself.Rate = ko.observable(0);

    innerself.Amount = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return innerself.Volume() * innerself.Rate();
            },
            write: function (value) {
                innerself.Volume(value / innerself.Rate()); // i do not know your algo 
            }
        }, innerself);
}
```

Comment: i guess this works but may i know the reason why break point not hitting in write function in my code?

Comment: as far as i understand from your view markup, you do not bind "AutoCalculate" to any input, don't you?

Comment: ok i believe write is used only if we want to write on the same observable we using for computed .

Comment: could you mark this as the answer, if it was helpful for you?

Comment: my pleasure to mark it . now with ur clues i made some digging now i understand what exactly i have to do .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are auto calculating amount, I don't see any logic in writing to computed observable. (which in your case depends on rate and quantity)

We can write to Amount observable from computed observable read function. If you want to catch both the changes in quantity and rate in a single observable (that is computed observable)

Your write method will not be called because you are not writing anything into the computed observable, but if you provide a text box or try to update like

```
  innerself.AutoCalculate(somevalue);
```

through code then write method will be called.

http://jsfiddle.net/2v3e7480/116/

I have edited the read method in computed observable to write to amount observable

```
innerself.Amount(innerself.Volume()*innerself.Rate());
```

and also I have removed all the subscriptions which I mentioned earlier.

So in effect if any of the rate or volume is changed, the amount is changed  and through the textbox you can change amount independently(Which by the way will not change computed observable).

Comment: ha yes if i can bind `AutoCalculate` it can be done direct way but i need to use `Amount` in my binding to display the calculated amount . reason behind is user can over ride the amount and save it . if i use as you mentioned i always get calculated value .

Comment: Provide the AutoCalculate there, then change the amount inside the autocalculate. In this way, if the user changes qty or rate, the autocalculate populates the amount and , then you can put some values in autocalculate textbox which overrides amount

Comment: @supercool And also you can subscribe to the amount observable and write back to computed observable, if you really want that to happen :). It's for you to put the logic of what happens when. I have updated the fiddle as per your comments

Comment: appreciated your efforts mate . that's a nice idea to subscribe but sadly as in ur fiddle when i change value in `rate` or `volume` the `amount` is not getting updated you can see i.e there is no chance subscribe getting fired.